# jQuery get value from a slideshow div and submit with form

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a slideshow that has a unique ref number for each slide. We want to include this reference number in a contact form text field, when its submitted.

We have it almost working but as the value of the DIV is constantly changing as its a slideshow. Its only getting the initial value of the DIV on page load, not at the point when the submit button is hit.

**The code we have to get the values is**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function prepareSubmit() {
      var getvalue = document.getElementById("refnum").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("input_2_5").value = getvalue;
      alert(document.getElementById("input_2_5").value);
      return true;
}
</script>
```

The HTML refnum is the div value that changes all the time:

```
<div id="refnum">Ref 4286</div>
<form name="test">
    <input type="text" id="input_2_5" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return prepareSubmit()" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Sure this is simple for anyone with more jQuery knowledge than I.

Thanks in advance : - )

Comment: Can you please add it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I created a test fiddle. Not sure if the OP is doing something like this though. Works Fine for me in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/ek02ryf1/1/

Comment: I changed the `<input>`  type to `button` in my fiddle to stop form submission though.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the div's value is not updating.

Comment: So as your jsfiddle when you clicked on the button it's placing correct reference number in the text field. What is the issue?

Comment: HI, The issue is that the value in the refnum div changes with each slide. and the current jsfiddle only captures the first slide value even after the slide changes and subsequently the value in the refnum div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you might be using a form in each slide right ?
if that is the case then you will need to use the reference of that slide. You can pass **this** on click or where you're calling your function.
You can wrap it up like this

```
<div class='parentDiv'>
    <div id="refnum">Ref 4286</div>
    <form name="test">
       <input type="text" id="input_2_5" name="text" />
       <input type="submit" onclick="return prepareSubmit(this)" value="submit" />
    </form>
<div>
```

And use jquery like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function prepareSubmit(self)
   {
      var value=$(self).parents("div.parentDiv").find('#refnum').Html();
      $('#input_2_5').val(value);
      alert($('#input_2_5').val());
   }
</script>
```

This should solve your purpose. If have any problem please let me know.

Comment: Its not a form in the slideshow. Its just a div that contains a meta value of a ref number from a custom field in a custom wordpress post type. We are using revolution slider to feed posts from this post type and display the data in a slide. As each slide changes the meta value changes but the current code will only capture the first slides value. Not any after that, as if it captures it on page load, not when the submit button is actually pressed which would capture it on that current slide. Hope that makes sense.